# How download multiple files with cURL?

Tags: bash, curl

I am using a range, but the files are overwritten

```
curl -o file.svg "example.com/[1-100]"
```

Comment: The `curl`  documentation deals with this very issue. See `man curl` and take a look at option `-o`.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412755).